# Detox not found testID in childrens components

Tags: react-native, testing, automated-tests, detox

I can not verify the existence of some TestID`s in some components themselves. What can it be? I already went from props but it does not work.

Comment: please provide some code and what you have done so far!! These two lines wouldn't be enough to get good help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this myself and discovered it isn't a Detox issue:

> ...React Native merges nested elements into one (seemingly untestable) element...
>
> ...testIDs are not bubbled to the container object (I don't think it's possible to achieve)...
>
> ...if there is no object, there is nothing to find by Detox.

Source: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/844